# Does Numpy array in Python select 'True' values by default when slicing data

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

test = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
t = test[test == 1]
print(t)
```

When I print 't' why is the code always going to print the "1" (i.e. "True") values only? Is there a behavior within a Numpy series to only select true values by default unless I define whether true or false?

I'm going through the Data Camp Python course and couldn't find the answer so reaching out to this group for help.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think `t = test[test == 1]` is doing?

Comment: Yes, this is a *feature* of `numpy.ndarray` objects called boolean indexing

Comment: `test[test.astype(bool)]` should do the same.  Or `test[np.where(test)]`.  Look at the items inside the [] by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you have written the variable `t` to be equal to the number 1 only. Whenever you print `t` the output will always be 1s. Try adding more different numbers to the list and print `t` again. You will also receive the array of 1s again.

When changing the value of the variable `test` to, say, 3, You will get at least a 3 from the array if exists. Otherwise, the array will be empty.

The same thing goes to the strings like `test == car`.

Update: slicing using index

Basically, you have been outputting  the numbers from their indices.

Let's see the following array

`x = np.array([1,0,1,1,1,0)`

Now, let's output 0,1,0, 0,0,1 by typing `x[x]`

Let's break the operation into pieces.

x is a variable for the numbers in the array. However, when including x in a square brackets like this `x[x]`, then you are literally ordering the program to output the first two numbers only from the array using the index.

Let's be more explicit. The indices of the array 1,0,1,1,1,0 are 0,1,2,3,45.

When typing x[0], then 1 will output only. Okay, let's try x[1]. It will output 0.  This is how the index works. x[x] will output 0,1,0,0,0,1 due to the indices given.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Even if I don't have test == 1, it still prints the default as '1'. Does it by default indexes to 1?

Comment: @P B did you change anything in the code? If you delete it it would print yhe whole list. Show me the edited code.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I'm trying to compare the following two sets of codes for my own understanding: 

#test 1
test = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,0,1])
t = test[test== 1]
print(t)

#test 2
test = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,0,1])
t = test[test]
print(t)

Why is the output in test 2 all 1s?

Comment: I have updated the answr above. You have been outputting the same number in the array using indices.